# Leading space in a WebStorm block comment

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm produces single line style comments the way I like it with a space after the `//`: `// comment here`. How do I add a space after the leading comment literal and before the closing one when commenting out blocks of code?
Here's what I have:

```
/*<line of code>
<line of code>
<line of code>*/
```

Here's what I'd like to have:

```
/* <line of code>
<line of code>
<line of code> */
```

`Add a space at comment start` won't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no way to control this, please feel free to file a request for this feature to youtrack. Related ticket: [IDEA-166872](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166872)